# Audio Player with True Variable Frequency Playback

Tags: windows, audio, mp3

I'm looking for an audio player that runs on Windows 10 and supports the following features:

- audio library (ability to remember a list of songs and sort them by artist, etc.)
- ability to play MP3 (and ideally MP4 and M4A) files
- *not* cloud-based, and software can run entirely offline
- *not* subscription-based; one-time purchase only
- **ability to play back any audio clip at a sample rate (or frequency, if you prefer) different than the recorded sample rate**

For this last point, I emphasize that I am **not** looking for the following:

- pitch adjustment (ability to modify pitch while keeping playback rate constant)
- playback rate adjustment (ability to modify playback rate while keeping pitch constant)

I am looking for *true* variable frequency playback whereby the software can pull in an MP3 recorded at 44.1 kHz, I can fiddle with a slider, knob, etc. and set playback to e.g. 40.65 kHz, click "Play", and the audio will play back at 40.65 kHz, with a corresponding decrease in pitch and increase in playback time.

The only audio player I've ever found with this capability was a program called "SuperSonic", which I still use in spite of its last release being in the year 2000. On Windows 10, it's *really* showing its age and I'd love a replacement, but any replacement *must* have the above functionality.

I'll code the thing myself if I have to, but if something already out there exists that meets these specs, it would make my year. Cost is no object.

My sincere thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite as fine control of the Audio speed as you are asking for but [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) Video and Audio player does offer a playback speed control and I am sure that it would be much simpler to code an extension for it, *if one doesn't already exist,* than to develop from scratch.

For your requirements:

- Windows 10 **Yes** *& 7 (95-ME in older editions or with extra download, even XP), Windows Phone, OSX, iOS, most Linux distros, Android, Solaris, QNX, ....*
- audio library (ability to remember a list of songs and sort them by artist, etc.) **Uses** *(and can access many existing formats of)* **playlists**
- ability to play MP3 (and ideally MP4 and M4A) files **Yes** *and MPEG Layer 1/2, MP3 - MPEG Layer 3, AAC - MPEG-4 part3, Vorbis, AC3 - A/52, E-AC-3, MLP / TrueHD>3, DTS, WMA 1/2, WMA 3, FLAC, ALAC, Speex, Musepack / MPC, ATRAC 3, Wavpack, Mod, TrueAudio, APE, Real Audio, Alaw/µlaw, AMR (3GPP), MIDI, LPCM, ADPCM, QCELP, DV Audio, QDM2/QDMC, MACE plus most video formats.*
- not cloud-based, and software can run entirely offline **Yes** *Installs totally on your local machine but can also play remote file &/or act as a media server*
- not subscription-based; one-time purchase only **No Subscription & No Purchase Price**
- ability to play back any audio clip at a sample rate (or frequency, if you prefer) different than the recorded sample rate **Current control is by speed factor but could be extended.**

Comment: I'll check it out. Many thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There is [AudioMass](https://audiomass.co/), a free and Open-Source player, that's working completely in the browser (also offline as [PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app)).

- The playback speed option is percent-based (with a resolution to 5 percent, with a slider control), but it actually increases pitch and speed at the same time and vice-versa (like in the old days).

[image: Changing speed with AudioMass dialog]

- It does not have a fully fledged library, but can store a set of "drafts" locally.
- It's working completely offline, installable as a Progressive Web App.